# Referring more than one user in comments

Tags: discussion, support

I am confused about why Stack Exchange doesn't let user refer more than one user in comments.

When a user is commenting, there is the possibility that user wants to refer some other users, and also give a reference of other user's suggestion.

> @xyz I agreed with the suggestion made by @abc // This is not allowed.

> @xyz I agreed with the suggestion made by abc // This is allowed.

Why when I press @ the first time I get a popup showing the username, and in the second case I don't get any hint about the username?

Can't we have a solution for this?

Comment: Given [a comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135228/pointing-more-than-one-user-in-comment-area#comment376944_135230) by the author: I think the above might not be about notifying, but about easily getting the names of multiple other users into a comment. For that, I'd rather not *see* the `@` in the end result. The part *"made by `@abc`"* really does not need the `@` nor any formatting, I feel. I'd like *"made by abc"* in the end result.

Comment: @Arjan yes exactly, I want to bring it in notice. As of now I will go with `@Tim ManishEarth` answer.

Comment: Okay, then note that Tim also states *If someone said "I like Shog9's idea better", you can easily guess that Shog9 is a user. So just drop the `@` when you want to mention a user.* No need for the `@` in your `@Tim ManishEarth` above either! (Actually, the proper English would be: *I will go with Tim's answer*...)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to just *mention* a user without notifying them, use backticks:

```
 @JeffAtwood I like `@Shog9`'s idea better
```

Shows

> @JeffAtwood I like `@Shog9`'s idea better

Really though, there's no pressibg need *to even be using the `@`*. Yes, it's internet code for "this is a username", but it's unnecessary in context-- If someone said "I like Shog9's idea better", you can easily guess that Shog9 is a user. So just drop the `@` when you want to mention a user.

---

If you want to *notify* two users, make two comments:

```
 @JeffAtwood I feel that blah blah blah blah blah. We ought to blah blah. Blah?
```

```
 /cc @Shog9
```

Note that comments are not for extended discussion. Use chat instead (which allows multiple @notifying)

Comment: making two comments its not a good idea, can't have mechanism that first occurance `@` will ping the user and second will be just.

Comment: @hotveryspicy It was changed because people thought that `@`-mentioning two users in a comment would ping both of them. If you just want to mention their name without pinging them, just leave off the `@` sign

Comment: @hot I don't get what you mean. The backtick syntax lets you mention users without pinging. Wanting to ping two users is a rare use case, ive had to do it extremely few times. Comments are for improving the post, not for discussion. As such, you only need a back and forth with the poster.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek agreed, Ok why it is happening that when I press `@` first time I got popup(username) and while second time there is no hint(username)?

Comment: @hotveryspicy The same reason; because you can't ping a second person, so why would it help you do the wrong thing?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Actually i don't want to ping the other user, I am thinking of user flexibility if the second username is typical or having some special character then also user need to write name manually.

Comment: @hot umm, the at-symbol is for pinging. Don't use it. Why do you absolutrly need the at? Also, `@replies` can be placed anywhere in a comment. How will the parser know whom to ping?

Comment: @TimManishEarth see when you writing @hot I am not at all notified? same thing I am thinking when user write `@` second time.

Comment: @hotveryspicy hmm, thats a bug. That's supposed to notify, maybe it got accidentally marked as read? Check your inbox. Still, my question standa: Why do you need the at? Just say `I agree with michaelmrozek`. The at doesn't add anything useful.

Comment: @TimManishEarth I just want that user need not to write other username if he write @ username will popup but not get pinged, by this user will have a flexibility and have less chance of spell mistakes of other user's name.

Comment: @hotveryspicy Three letters are enough (as long as unambiguous, anyway), and the comments here using `@hot` are indeed in your inbox. Why do you say you're not notified?

Comment: @balpha I said because "I am not at all notified". When I again came to this page then I came to know that update is made.

Comment: @hotveryspicy I don't understand. Are you saying the comments using `@hot` are not in your global inbox (top left of the page)? Because I can see they are.

Comment: @balpha: Sometimes certain inbox notifications mark themselves as read. It's pretty random, never been able to pin it down. Could've been that.

Comment: @balpha I mean to say that, when `@Tim ManishEarth` wrote `@hot` I dint got any *Red colored notification(top left of the page)*. Yes exactly what `@Tim ManishEarth` mentioned in last comment.

Comment: The problem with Chat is that it totally sucks for some communities; though questions on SO get answered, the focus of the tag/community is elsewhere (e.g., normal IRC) and the noobs won't know it.

Comment: As for *"If you want to just mention a user without notifying them, use backticks"*, I'd rather see the `@` dropped instead, hence *"@JeffAtwood I like Shog9's idea better"*. You've mentioned that in the comments at least twice too; care to edit that into the answer? (I'd say that the code/backticks workaround is merely to be used for examples *about* the notifications; not for use in regular comments. I think the error messages once mentioned the backticks, but currently it's just *"Only one additional @user can be notified; the post owner will always be notified"*.)

Comment: @arjan will do, on mobile now ..