# Why can't I ping more than one user at once?

Tags: discussion, comments, notifications, comment-replies

Perhaps this has been answered before, but I've only found oblique references ([1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/291201), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135228/291201), [3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186272/cant-mention-more-than-one-user-in-a-comment-on-my-question)).

I often find that it makes perfect sense to try and notify two users (neither being the post owner) at once within a single comment; why is it that this practice is prohibited? Something about spam prevention?

The workaround of simply writing two comments seems silly. Why would this practice be allowed if double-pinging is discouraged?

Comment: I do find this strange also, considering that in the chat, you can ping many users at once; and the chat requires only 20 reps to talk, while commenting requires 50 rep (except there, where requirement is 5).

Comment: I can't believe there isn't a good answer to this anywhere in this place. :/

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks, it's admittedly hard to search this. I'll leave this here in case someone else Googles their way down my path.